# Risk Measure-identication

Tags: risk-management, value-at-risk, coherent-risk-measure

Let X be a variable with existing moment generating function $M_x(z)=E[e^{zX}]$.
Define the following risk measure: $\rho_{\alpha}(X)=inf_{z>0}(z^{-1}ln(\frac{M_x(z)}{1-\alpha}))$

Does anyone know the name of this risk measure?
Also, how could I prove this function is subadditive?

Comment: It is the Entropic Value at Risk https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2465750/how-to-calculate-the-distortion-function-for-evar See also here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_value_at_risk

Comment: For a proof a sub-additivity: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/45227/prove-subadditivity-entropic-value-at-risk/45313#45313